# Proportionately reducing a set of numbers to balance a total

Tags: java, math

Within my code I have groups of items which total 100. Ie there is a total number of items in each group and the total number for all groups is 100.

Now, if the user decides to change one of the counts, i want all the others to scale so as they are still in the same ratio to each other, but the total count is still 100.

ie if we started with

```
[20, 30, 50]
```

and you changed the 50 to 75
then you would end up with

```
[10, 15, 75]
```

so what I need is a function which takes arguments of index and the new value
And adjusts the values in the array to balance them.

Pseudocode would be amazing! Java even more so!

Comment: How do you intend to handle rounding?  [11, 19, 70] -> [?, ?, 75]

Comment: It doesnt need to be perfect, so I was aiming to round them all to the nearest int, then add/subtract from the largest number to even things out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add the numbers of the non-user change numbers, get their ratios to this number, and make sure that the ration doesn't change when you try to increase or decrease the numbers.

e.g.

- say that: a + b + c + d = 100
- and say the user adds deltaA to a,

then

```
int newB = (int) (b * ((double)b + c + d - deltaA) / (b + c + d))
```

and the same for the others:

```
int newC = (int) (c * ((double)b + c + d - deltaA) / (b + c + d)) 
int newD = (int) (d * ((double)b + c + d - deltaA) / (b + c + d))
```

Note, this has *nothing* to do with Java, and really nothing to do with programming but rather it's nothing more than algebra at its most basic. Also note that this solution may be over or under 100 by 1 or 2 due to the challenge of rounding. You'll have to do a little fudging with this.

Comment: I thought this is exactly what I had done, however it didnt seem to work. After copying what you have put and changing the variable names it *did* work.
The reason for the asterisks is it works if the user increases the value. However if they decrease the value it doesn't and I am struggling to understand why!

Comment: @user2036256: If they decrease the value, then deltaA is a negative number, but the equation is completely unchanged.